# Implicit downcast from 'System.IO.Stream' to 'System.IO.MemoryStream'

Tags: .net, casting, unity-game-engine, downcast, unityscript

```
function SerializeObject(pObject : Object)
{
   var XmlizedString : String  = null;
   var memoryStream : MemoryStream  = new MemoryStream();
   var xs : XmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlData));
   var xmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter  = new XmlTextWriter(memoryStream, Encoding.UTF8);
   xs.Serialize(xmlTextWriter, pObject);
   memoryStream = xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
   XmlizedString = UTF8ByteArrayToString(memoryStream.ToArray());
   return XmlizedString;
}
```

The problem lies in the line:

```
memoryStream = xmlTextWriter.BaseStream;
```

I am aware that xmlTextWriter.BaseStream is of the type stream, but how would I go about typecasting it?

thanks for any help in advanced!

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to JavaScript??

Comment: Are you sure that's javascript? Also, if those classes are anything like I'd expect, why do you need to extract the `BaseStream` from the `xmlTextWriter`? Isn't it just the same stream that was already referenced by the `memoryStream` variable, and passed into the `XmlTestWriter` constructor?

Comment: its javascript, but applied to Unity3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `as` for reference types.

Try:

```
memoryStream = xmlTextWriter.BaseStream as MemoryStream;
```

See this question for more details: [How to perform Explicit typecasting in UnityScript?](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/279809/how-to-perform-explicit-typecasting-in-unityscript.html)